# What is the political stance of the Biden administration on the Right to Repair, and do its policies on it reflect that?

Tags: united-states, policy, joe-biden, federalism, lobbying

As an advocate for [Right to Repair](https://www.ifixit.com/Right-to-Repair), I have been closely following the Right to Repair movement in the US. It seems to have reached a tipping point in America too, and [more than 25 US states](https://www.vice.com/en/article/z3vavw/half-the-country-is-now-considering-right-to-repair-laws) are considering introducing / amending Right to Repair laws:

> The right-to-repair movement is poised to explode in 2021. When your stuff breaks, you should be able to fix it yourself. Tech manufactures want to control the methods of repair and companies such as Apple and John Deere do so at the detriment of their customers. But people across the world are tired of it and 25 states in the U.S. are considering right-to-repair legislation in 2021.

However, despite states like [New York](https://9to5mac.com/2022/06/03/right-to-repair-new-york/) and California passing laws, they continue to face substantial political hurdles.

As far as I understand the Federal nature of political governance in the US, Federal laws can trump State laws that conflict with it. And this has sometimes been (mis)used to find or create loopholes around some State laws by the Federal government. And so the opponents of the Right to Repair movement are now apparently lobbying the current Biden administration to *subvert* the intent of the State laws on Right to Repair, through Federal laws and regulations.

One very recent example of this is described in this [video by Louis Rossman](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2nXVljRUnoc), that highlights how an agency of the Federal government has provided an "advisory" that allows automobile manufacturers to ignore / bypass provisions of the Right to Repair laws passed by some states.

From what I understand, the Biden administration has claimed that it supports the Right to Repair movement but it doesn't wish to consider it as a *consumer right* issue:

> “What’s happened [is] a lot of these companies said, ‘You’re right. We’re going to voluntarily do it. You don’t have to order us to do it,’ ” Biden said at Monday’s meeting.
>
> ... The Biden administration has couched right to repair as a competition issue, arguing that that diminished repair options increase consumer costs and crowd out independent repair shops. - [Biden highlights ‘right to repair’ wins](https://thehill.com/policy/technology/591217-biden-highlights-right-to-repair-wins/)

And so the the actions of the US Federal government don't show the same level of commitment as being displayed by some US States, who are treating this as a consumer right issue, and are actually creating strong legislations to support it.

1. What is the political stand of the Biden administration on the Right to Repair movement?
2. Has it evolved due to the political discussions generated by the various State legislation debates, and / or lobbying?
3. Do the policies of the Biden administration actually reflect their public stance on the issue, or has it since been diluted due to pressure from lobbyists (as is claimed by some critics)?

(Please ensure your answer is backed by what they have publicly said and actually done).

Comment: skeptics.se is a sight dedicated for these kind of fact-check questions that generally has high quality answers.

Comment: @RyanJensen Not for political subjects. I find Po.SE is less politically biased and since this deals with actual policy and political decision making, Po.SE can provide better answers. (If the term "fact checking" distracts from that, then we can edit the question).

Comment: @RyanJensen This question is about the general policy of the administration, Skeptics would require a specific notable claim.

Comment: @sfxedit *" I find Po.SE is less politically biased"* Reality has a well known liberal bias, they say...